# Rails 6 Mina deploy fails at Precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, debian-buster, mina-deploy

I am running a Debian 10 (Buster) Server for my Rails 6.0.3, Ruby 2.6.3, Mina 1.2.3 app. When I run Mina deploy it errors out but does not give me enough to help me understand what I need to do to resolve the issue.

Mina Deploy output

```
Precompiling asset files
       $ RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile
       Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /var/www/site/tmp/build-15965768145748/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
        2: from /var/www/site/tmp/build-15965768145748/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        1: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/specifications/default/exe/rake (LoadError)
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
```

Deploy.rb

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'

set :application_name, 'site'
set :domain, 'server'
set :user, 'deployer'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/site"
set :repository, "git@github.com:git.git"
set :branch, 'master'
set :rvm_use_path, '/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh'

set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

task :remote_environment do
   ruby_version = File.read('.ruby-version').strip
   raise "Couldn't determine Ruby version: Do you have a file .ruby-version in your project root?" if ruby_version.empty?

   invoke :'rvm:use', 'ruby-2.6.3'
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy do
   deploy do
     invoke :'git:clone'
     invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
     invoke :'bundle:install'
     invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
     invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
     invoke :'deploy:cleanup'
     on :launch do
     end
   end
end

namespace :passenger do
desc "Restart Passenger"
   task :restart do
     queue %{
       echo "-----> Restarting passenger"
       cd #{deploy_to}/current
       #{echo_cmd %[mkdir -p tmp]}
       #{echo_cmd %[touch tmp/restart.txt]}
     }
   end
end
```

I have made sure that yarn is installed and working on my Production machine. When I run the precompile on the Production machine, it runs through successfully. But still errors out in the Mina Deploy with no change in the error text. I have looked into [this article](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/docs/faq.md#--my_program-not-found-but-is-already-installed)  In doing so I have commented out the suggested code snippet just to test, but that did not change anything. In looking at my bashrc, I do not see any snippets with EXPORT or SOURCE at the beginning of them.

EDIT: When I run the precompile on the server side, each new deployment folder seems like it will give me this issue.

Comment: When you testing on the production machine are you sure that you are using rvm or potentially the system packages?